# Concatenate the value of a textbox with a link and use it in an href (HTML)

Tags: javascript, href, html

I have some problems passing the text value of a textbox to a href. I want to do something like this:

```
<div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
   <label for="inputWord" class="sr-only">word</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputWord" placeholder="Word">
</div>
```

And then I want to do a google search:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" href="https://www.google.com.uy/search?q=" + 'inputWord' target="_blank">Search</a>
```

I know that it's wrong but I've no idea about how to make it work. I put everything inside a form.

Comment: You need something called _javascript_

Comment: I assumed, but what should I write in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Replace a tag element with button

```
<button onclick="doSearch()">Search</button>
<script>
 function doSearch() {
  let word = document.querySelector('#inputWord').value;
  window.location = "https://www.google.com.uy/search?q=" + word;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is collect the form value and send it as a variable to the link with js.

This script sends data when the input field has Changed

```
<div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2"> 
    <label for="inputWord" class="sr-only">word</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputWord" placeholder="Word" onChange="setHref(this.value)"> </div>

<script>
    function setHref(val){
        document.getElementsByClassName("btn").setAttribute("href", val)
    }
</script>
```